# Exporting mixed data of matrices and vectors / lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, export, vector

thank you for reading my question.

I have a problem trying to export mixed data from Mathematica. I have different matrices and vectors, which should be combined to a output file.

Here a minimal-working-example:

```
a = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
b = {{4}, {5}, {6}};
c = {7, 8, 9};
d = Transpose[{a, b, c}];
Export["test.txt", d, "TSV"]
```

The output file is:

```
{1} {4} 7
{2} {5} 8
{3} {6} 9
```

I would like to have the output like this, similar to "//TableForm":

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how I may achive this. Changing the format, e.g. to Table or CSV did not change anything. How may I export the data correctly?

Thank you in advance for answering my question.

Comment: `d = Transpose[{Flatten@a, Flatten@b, c}];`?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Like always, if you know the answer its trivial. I'll write a answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The lists "a" and "b" are nested lists. With the [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) option, the nested lists my be flattened and the nesting removed.

The answer is, as posted from [Öskå](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1356/%C3%96sk%C3%A5), to use the Flatten[]-command before the Transpose[]-command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are all the same length

```
Transpose[Flatten /@ {a, b, c}]
```

But beware that for ragged lists (i.e., those with sub-lists that are not all the same length) Transpose will not work and you have to use `Flatten` again.

```
a = {{0}, {1}, {{2}}, {3}};
b = {{4}, {5}, {6}};
c = {7, 8, 9};

Flatten[Flatten /@ {a, b, c}, {2}]
```

> Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} cannot be transposed. >>

```
Flatten[Flatten /@ {a, b, c}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 4, 7}, {1, 5, 8}, {2, 6, 9}, {3}}
> ```

As explained [here](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/whats-in-docs/)